# What's the appropriate way to signify an S-Corp?

Tags: united-states, small-business, s-corporation, business

If I have traditional company called Acme then I'd write:

**Acme, Inc**

If it were an LLC:

**Acme, LLC**

If it were a Limited Partnership (I think -- I'm basing this on LucasFilm):

**Acme, Ltd.**

If I were a sole proprietor:

**John Blaze, SP**

How about for S-Corp?

Comment: I've literally never, ever, seen SP.  If you had a corporation you'd have Acme, Inc.  "Traditional company" doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

S-Corp is a corporation. I.e.: you add a "Inc." or "Corp." to the name or something of that kind. "S" denotes a specific tax treatment which may change during the lifetime of the corporation. It doesn't refer to a legal status.

Answer (score 5):

[Subchapter S Corporations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_corporation) are a special type of corporation; the difference is how they are taxed, not how they relate to their vendors or customers.  As a result, they are named the same way as any other corporation.

The rules on names of corporations vary by state.  "Corporation" and "Incorporated" (and their abbreviations) are allowed by every state, but some states allow other names as well.  The Wikipedia article ["Types of business entity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_business_entity) lists an [overview of corporation naming rules for each state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_business_entity#Corporations).

The S-Corp that I work for has "Inc." at the end of its name.